# Table loses alignment when jquery drop down feature is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I added the following code to make the table drop down, it went out of alignment.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
      $("table").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I also added the "display:none;" attribute to the table so it would only appear after drop down was initiated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try recreating this in JFiddle with the html so we can recreate the problem.

Comment: The drop down element must be `position:absolute`.

Comment: Without a [mcve] that reproduces problem nobody here can help